# Vector variable giving me negative values for positives

Tags: r

I wrote `c()` in R, `a<--c(2,4,6,8)`, but when I execute this and try to run vector variable a, I'm getting values like `-2,-4,-6,-8`, wondering why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
a <-c(2,4,6,8)
```

the second - is interpreted as:

```
a <-  -c(2,4,6,8)
```

Thus making all numbers negative.

Comment: oh :-) Thanks Jan

Comment: you're welcome! please upvote the answer and mark it as "accepted" so everyone knows this issue is solved